# No Firefox cookies.sqlite file found. Use -c COOKIEFILE

Tags: firefox, kali-linux, sqlite

I try to execute the code by using this command in my Kali Linux python3 `./cookies.py`

then I got this message `No Firefox cookies.sqlite file found. Use -c COOKIEFILE.`

what does the message mean and what is the solution to repair it?

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Cookies.sqlite It is a file Firefox stores cookies in.

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: all right, I expected it to work perfectly.

Comment: Okay, lets go back to basic faultfinding. Based on the error you get *do you have firefox installed? Do you **use** firefox for it to have set up a profile? Have you gone to some website that would set up cookies in it that this script would presumably catch?* Apart from "I ran some random script and expected it to work" what have you done? What do you need this script to do? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? You can choose to be a part of the problem or you can actually help to solve it.

Comment: Your previous (now deleted) question suggests you could be using WSL. Any answer about WSL would be very different to one on a proper Kali machine. You should provide more information as expecting a Kali WSL VM to have access to your host machine version of Firefox is not going to be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

See the article
[Solving Firefox cookies.sqlite File Not Found Error](https://pupuweb.com/fix-firefox-cookies-sqlite-file-not-found-error/):

> **Understanding the Error**
>
> When you execute a Python script in Kali Linux using the command
> `python3 ./cookies.py`, you might encounter the error message “No
> Firefox cookies.sqlite file found. Use -c COOKIEFILE”. This error
> occurs when the script is unable to locate the cookies.sqlite file,
> which is typically found in the Firefox profile directory.
>
> **How to Resolve the “No Firefox cookies.sqlite file found” Error**
>
> To fix this issue, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open your file manager.
> 2. Navigate to `~/.mozilla/firefox/`.
> 3. Look for a directory ending with `.default`.
> 4. Within the profile directory, find the `cookies.sqlite` file.
> 5. Use the -c option to specify the path to `cookies.sqlite`:
>
>    ```
>    python3 ./cookies.py -c /path/to/your/cookies.sqlite
>    ```